# How about the singularities of $\sqrt z$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Singularities of principal square root function ? I know it has non isolated singularities but how?

Comment: What do you mean by the "principal square root" if the tag is complex analysis?

Comment: I mean I want to know about the singularities of √z where z is complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of $\sqrt z$ near $z=0$ is called [branch point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point).
Moreover, it has a branch cut in the negative real axis.

Comment: So what is the difference b/w branch point and non isolated singularity? Can branch points be treated as non isolated singularities?

Comment: @Henry branch points show the multivalueness of a function, non isolated singularities does not. No.